# How to search database for matching elements

Tags: php, sql

What I want is a loop that goes though each row within the genre table searching for film id matches and if there are matches print them. So far what I getting is this :
[image]

```
<?php
while($row_movie_list['film_id'] = $row_genre['id_film'])
{
        if ($row_film_genre['id_genre'] = $row_genre['id_genre'])
            {
                echo $row_film_genre['genre'];
            }
            else {echo 'noting';}
    }

?>
```

Comment: You should not loop the the enitre table for this, but rather filter your result set using a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Romance Romance Rom.... what sort of movie DB is this?

Answer (score 3):

You're doing an assignment in your if statement instead of a comparison:

```
while($row_movie_list['film_id'] = $row_genre['id_film'])
```

should be

```
while($row_movie_list['film_id'] == $row_genre['id_film'])
```

This assumes that one of those values will potentially change elsewhere in your loop. If not you're still going to be in an infinite loop.

Comment: I have changed it and still stuck in the loop. Is there a way to get the value of how many matches there are and loop that many times ?

Comment: See Mike Brant's comment above